# Why does Android window manager framework have a explicit loop count?

Tags: java, android, frameworks, orientation, screen-orientation

I was trying to understand the screen orientation change sequence in the Android operating system when I came across the file WindowManagerService.java
This file is responsible for freezing the display, setting custom animations, computing a new configurations and then finally communicating with the activity manager to resume the activity upon completing rotation.

One function kept bugging me.

```
private final void performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked() {

    int loopCount = 6;
    do {
        mTraversalScheduled = false;
        performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop();
        mH.removeMessages(H.DO_TRAVERSAL);
        loopCount--;
    } while (mTraversalScheduled && loopCount > 0);
    mInnerFields.mWallpaperActionPending = false;
}
```

Now this function is responsible for making all the layout transitions of all the windows. I do not understand why is it called a specific of **"6" times**?? In all the other places that I have seen we get the number of windows and then perform the desired operations. Is there a specific answer for 6 iterations? Why 6?

Any kind of information will be helpful. The source code can be seen at this [link](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/WindowManagerService.java#8601).

Comment: why do you need to know that?  it's a private, internal method implementing some action,  why is it so important to understand rotation changes?

Comment: @pskink Because those who developed android, some days were curious about internal and private methods inside other applications...

Comment: @nikoo28 Maybe this link help you : (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2514846&page=10)

Comment: @pskink Because everywhere else, android has obtained the number of windows and then performed operations upon them. This case must be something special, you can consider this question as a part of my curiosity..